# When entry is an array, why only the last file is packed to output file in webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-5

Following is my directory structure:

src

|---index1.js

|---index2.js

package.json

webpack.config.js

Content of src/index1.js:

```
export function Func1() {
    return 1111;
}
```

Content of src/index2.js:

```
export function Func2() {
    return 2222;
}
```

Content of webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index2.js', './src/index1.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

The output of webpack is:

```
!function(e,o){if("object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module)module.exports=o();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],o);else{var t=o();for(var r in t)("object"==typeof exports?exports:e)[r]=t[r]}}(self,(()=>(()=>{"use strict";var e={d:(o,t)=>{for(var r in t)e.o(t,r)&&!e.o(o,r)&&Object.defineProperty(o,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t[r]})},o:(e,o)=>Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,o),r:e=>{"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})}},o={};return(()=>{function t(){return 1111}e.r(o),e.d(o,{Func1:()=>t})})(),o})()));
```

Only Func1 is packed to main.js. Func2 is missing.

Why? I thought webpack should pack both src/index1.js and src/index2.js to output file.

Following is from webpack official doc:

> We can also pass an array of file paths to the entry property which creates what is known as a "multi-main entry". This is useful when you would like to inject multiple dependent files together and graph their dependencies into one "chunk".

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. What's the webpack version? Is this all the code?

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/timewalker08/webpack-demo

Comment: Version is 5.84.1

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. See [output.library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) documentation:

> If you provide an array as the entry point, only the last one in the array will be exposed.

```js
module.exports = {
  // …
  entry: ['./src/a.js', './src/b.js'], // only exports in b.js will be exposed
  output: {
    library: 'MyLibrary',
  },
};
```

package version:

```json
"webpack": "^5.80.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
```

Comment: If only the last one is exposed, what the meaning to pass array to entry?

Comment: But following also from official document: We can also pass an array of file paths to the entry property which creates what is known as a "multi-main entry". This is useful when you would like to inject multiple dependent files together and graph their dependencies into one "chunk".